# SysPref > Keyboard > Text auto-spell-correct is OFF but persists in Numbers

Tags: macos, keyboard, spellcheck, autocorrect

I switched off spell-correct in SysPref > Keyboard > Text, but Numbers 3.2 continues not only to suggest corrections, but - when I decline the suggestion by hitting ESC - to replace my text with its suggestion.  How utterly annoying of it!  Any idea how to shut it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you unchecked "Show suggestions when editing table cells" in the Numbers Preferences panel? ( <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> )

[image: Numbers Pref panel]